# How would I describe this domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today I tried to create geometric constructions on Desmos, a convenient online graphing utility. I did my best to make the given points draggable, just to show that the construction is true in all cases of the given. It's going quite well, and I have created a working example for the simple construction of an equilateral triangle given a side. You can access it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4uoawzcgr8). The problem I am having is with the domain, and I can't see to figure a mathematical way around it. Let me explain.

Let's say I have the following:

$y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\left(x-x_1\right)\left\{x_1<x<x_2\right\}$

Essentially I am graphing a line and restricting its domain such that it appears to connect two points, ($x_1$, $y_1$) and ($x_2$, $y_2$). This works perfectly, and if I change the location of those two points, the line will appear to move with it. The problem arises when I move ($x_2$, $y_2$) to the left of ($x_1$, $y_1$). When this happens, I still want a line segment to appear to connect the two points. However, due to my domain restriction, no line will appear! Basically, I'm asking how I can combine $\left\{x_1<x<x_2\right\}$ and $\left\{x_1>x>x_2\right\}$ into one neat expression. I must be overlooking something obvious, so I apologize in advance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not able to ascertain what the question is.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Basically, how can I combine {x1 < x < x2} and {x2 < x < x1} into one domain? The accepted answer was sufficient, as {min(x1,x2) <= x <= max(x1,x2)} would combine both domains.

Comment: @KITTENDESTROYER-9000 Didn't you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to describe the interval between $x_1$ and $x_2$ would be

$$\min(x_1, x_2) \le x \le \max(x_1, x_2)$$

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked the use of min() and max()! Thanks for the super quick reply!